# Is Linux Virtual Server old, or is it standing still?

Tags: linux, load-balancing, lvs

Based on this question: [Widely-used load balancing solutions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/124905/widely-used-load-balancing-solutions), LVS may be the right solution for my problem.

But when I went to its homepage http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/, I found that LVS has been updated since Nov, 2008. The world's moving fast, and I don't know if LVS was obsolete or not.

Is LVS standing still, or there're some better solutions to replace it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: It looks from the web site like a new version of the ipvsadm management tool was released Feb 2011.  The actual LVS implementation is in the Linux kernel though and is currently maintained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use it currently in a highly available production environment serving numerous public users.  I swear by it and would encourage you to give it a try.

With that said, there are alternatives depending on your application and preference.  These include:

- [Haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)
- [Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound)
- [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) - web proxy that has load balancing features

Comment: It may be a bug that I can't vote up this answer!

Comment: These are actually L7 proxy, not L4 director. They terminate TCP connections and LVS (or other L4 directors) don't. If you put VRRP/OSPF/ECMP on them, the TCP connections will be disturbed on a node-failure scenario.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2016 the LVS code is still maintained in the Linux kernel tree   as a subset of the netfilter code. In the kernel tree check under: [...net/netfilter/ipvs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/netfilter/ipvs) and [...Documentation/networking/ipvs-sysctl.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ipvs-sysctl.txt)

The ipvsadm tooling is stable, not obsolete and can still be downloaded from http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/software/ipvs.html

As far as I can tell IPv6 support for IPVS never made it past the experimental stage so that may be detractor.

The active development is now primarily found in [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) that builds on LVS.

Comment: The current documentation seems to be located here https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ipvs-sysctl.rst
IPv6 support seems to be present in projects building upon IPVS: https://raymii.org/s/articles/Adding_IPv6_to_a_keepalived_and_haproxy_cluster.html so this probably evolved since 2016.

Answer (score 0):

We use components of the LVS for high availability solutions (specifically, keepalived to float virtual IPs from server to server as required).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it is old. But: It is stable.

We use it in conjunction with another "old" add-on: lvs-kiss.
That one seems to be pretty "dead" too.

The best about lvs is that it is fast. This is because it works on layer 2/3 - which is also its greatest drawback. It has no idea what a http-session is.

Tomcat does - you can put lvs in front of any service - if each of the servers providing that service does share its session information with the other servers you will have a pretty good combination.

The only drawback of LVS is IMHO the fixed time setting for replicating (ip-)session informatation to a slave lvs-server.