# Sharing Windows 7 NLB in home network

Tags: windows, windows-7, load-balancing, nlb

I have read [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/124905/widely-used-load-balancing-solutions) and have been googling trying to do what is in the title, with no luck. I´ve tried bridging connections, ICS, etc.

I have two separate internet connections from two different companies at my disposal. I have got the NLB in Windows 7 working using these two connections. The computer I am using for this task has two NICs and one wifi card. I´ve used the wifi card and a NIC for the NLB and works well, as well as using the two NICS for the NLB.

But now I need to share this NLB connection in my home network. Is this possible to do using only Windows 7 or what can the experts recommend?

Alternately, should I be looking at another OS?

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should get an appliance like a router or L3 switch that can load-balance connections across multiple uplinks. Trying to do this on Windows 7 is not a great idea. It wasn't designed to act as a router, nevermind one that load balances multiple WAN uplinks.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts MDMarra, however without getting into additional hardware, is there any 3rd party software that could help me achieve this?

Comment: You can probably do this with an OS that's more suited for work as a router, like one of the BSDs or Linux. Over the long-haul, the electricity required to run a full-blown desktop will more than overcome buying a dedicated piece of hardware, though.

Comment: Just want to make sure it can´t be done with Windows 7?, since the Desktop I have already has it installed. Then I will try Linux, any recommendations? And thanks again

Comment: This is a site for professionals. No professional is ever going to try and configure this in their environment using Windows 7. It's a desktop OS. It was never intended to do routing, the little functionality that is there was bolted on as an afterthought. If you want any kind of reliability (which is the cornerstone of being a professional) you'll use an OS that has this built-in, like one of the BSDs, or you'll buy a multi-uplink router than can aggregate or round-robin the connections.

Comment: @Andrew It can't be done with Win7 without 3rd party software. [pfSense](http://pfsense.org) can do this out of the box and it's pretty easy to configure (nice web interface).

Comment: Thank you for your input MDMarra, I understand that this shouldn´t be done on Windows 7, it was not designed for this, and so this is why I asked the community because I have not delved in this topic until now. @Chris S thank you, I will look into pfSense!